# Flux through a surface - Multivariable Calculus

Tags: calculus

Regarding this problem :

Compute the field flux for a given field

$$\vec{F} = (x^3-2y^2)\hat{i}+(e^{2x}+y^3)\hat{j}+(z^2-xy)\hat{k}$$

Through part of the surface $z=-(x^2+y^2)$ that is located above $z=-4$ plane (not including the plane itself)
in the direction of a normal that satisfies $\cos(\hat{n},z)<0$

The only thing I can't figure out, is the part with the cos, which I'm not familiar with this notation. 
How do I read it? What does it mean?

Comment: I think you mean $\cos(\hat{n},\hat{k})<0$ rather than $\cos(\hat{n},z)<0$, i.e., $\hat{n}\cdot\hat{k}<0$, so it is pointing in a direction of decreasing $z$.

Comment: first of all, thank you for the help with the editing the formulas (tried to post them correctly)
And in the question it's written $\cos(\hat{n},z)<0$

Comment: @Excel265 Can you solve the question, after knowing what the notation meant?

Answer (score 1):

Although not very sure, I guess "$z$" in the notation $\cos(\hat{n},z)$ is a vector pointing in the direction of "**positive**" $z$-axis. If $\cos(\hat{n},z)<0$, then the included angle between $\hat{n}$ and $z$ must be greater than 180 degrees. So $\hat{n}$ points **inside** the paraboloid. That is, downward and away the $xy$-plane.